# Unlock the micro sd card

Tags: permissions, mass-storage, micro-sd

There is no physical switch. I've tried many application software in windows and Linux but yet still not working. I think the last time I can modify the micro sd card content is where I make deletion and copying on the phone mode. After I formatted the phone, the micro sd card is no longer content-editable. I've tried formatted the micro sd but not working. Any suggestion to keep use?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, have you tried copying and removing card content from terminal?

**To open terminal**

ctrl + alt + t

**To copy**

$ sudo cp /media/user/file /destination

**To remove**

$ sudo rm /media/user/file

Comment: Using that method was just fine, in our view we see it was deleted without error but after plug in back, the content was still at there

Comment: $ chown -R username /media,  after you execute this command can you make changes?